# Import func from file in diffrent directory kotlin

Tags: file, kotlin, import

I have a file structure that looks like this -

`-- Parent Dir --
  -- Dir a --
    - main.kt
  -- Dir b --
    - app.kt`

Let's say app.kt has a function `fun meaningOfLife():Int{return 42}` 
How do I import `meaningOfLife` in main.kt

Comment: What is the package specified at the top of app.kt file? You typically have a directory structure that matches exactly with the package structure. And you import classes and functions from its package, not from a directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The folder structure doesn't strictly speaking matter too much. What is important is the packages (though these should generally match the folder structure in some way), and whether you're separating the project into different modules (which I'm assuming in this case you're not). I take it your `meaningOfLife` function isn't in a class, it's just a top-level function in a ".kt" file?  If so, just add an `import` statement at the top of your "main.kt" file with the package name and the method pointing at the definition of the `meaningOfLife` function.  e.g. if "app.kt" has this:

```
package com.something.b

fun meaningOfLife()...
```

Then in "main.kt" you should have this:

```
package com.something.a

import com.something.b.meaningOfLife

fun test() {
    meaningOfLife()
}
```

Comment: could you include a compiling folder structure?